# How to send an object from a mousePressed event in a Frame/Panel in ViewA to ViewB in eclipse 3.x RCP?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

In ViewA, I have a panel within a frame being displayed. When I click on an object within this panel, I would like to send the object to a function in ViewB.

```java
public class ViewA extends ViewPart{

    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {

          Composite swtAwtComponent = new Composite(parent, SWT.EMBEDDED);
          java.awt.Frame frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame( swtAwtComponent );
          javax.swing.JPanel panel = new javax.swing.JPanel( );
           ...
     }
}


public class ViewB extends ViewPart{

...

        public void foo(Object o){
        }

}
```

I have seen many questions here regarding communicating between two views, using an ISelectionListener, and a link to the vogella tutorials on commands such as; [Eclipse RCP let two views communicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832551/eclipse-rcp-let-two-views-communicate), [Eclipse RCP update a View after changes in the editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829797/eclipse-rcp-update-a-view-after-changes-in-the-editor?rq=1) etc. However, every question's solution assumes the triggering event is a selection within a TableViewer (or any viewer) and not within a Frame/Panel mousePressed event. Please help.

Comment: Implement your own `ISelectionProvider` for ViewA and set the selection on each mouse press event.

Comment: @greg-449 To test if the event is firing: In my ViewA creatPartControl function, I have:

' getSite().setSelectionProvider(this);
ISelectionProvider selectionProvider = getViewSite().getSelectionProvider();
selectionProvider.setSelection(new StructuredSelection("test"));'

And in ViewB createPartControl which implements ISelectionListener: 
'getViewSite().getPage().addSelectionListener("version1.views.ViewA",(ISelectionListener)this);
getViewSite().getPage().addSelectionListener(this);'

I am not detecting the firing of the event although it is set to fire when the view is loaded.